# Can "more" be used without "than"?

Tags: grammar, ellipsis

As I'm getting familiar with English grammar, I'm facing a few doubts. The word *more* is a comparative form of *much* (for non-countable nouns) and *many* (with countable nouns). However, I can use *more* with sentences which don't have comparisons. e.g.,

> As business grows more complex, I'm unable to handle it.

How would you explain this usage of more. Can this work as an adjective as well without having comparisons? Or the usage of *than* is implied. e.g.

> As business grows more complex [than did in past], I'm unable to handle it.

Comment: "Please, sir," replied Oliver, "I want some more." — _Oliver Twist, Charles Dickens_

Comment: @IanMacDonald I think it is fair to say that there is an implicit than-clause in every comparative: "Please, sir," replied Oliver, "I want some more [than this]."

Comment: @j4nd3r53n: Is there? Or is it " I want some more [of this]" ?

Comment: "We need more power!" - this implies that the existing level of power is not sufficient.

Comment: @MSalters I think it’s actually _of that_. Oliver had finished his food.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n Even if that were so (and I'm with MSalters that it isn't), I can think of plenty more examples.

Comment: One of the most repeated phrases in the English language: "But wait! There's more!"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The comparative, whether formed with **more** or with **-er**, doesn't need a *than*-clause to function.

For example, all of the following sentences are valid uses of the comparative:

> John grew **smarter**.
>
> Felicia became **more adept** at her work.
>
> As business grows **more complex**, I have trouble handling it.

In the first example, the suffix **-er** marks the comparative. In the second and third examples, **more** functions as an adverb to mark the comparative of that adjective. (See [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/comparison-adjectives-bigger-biggest-more-interesting) for information on these forms.)

All of these examples are comprehensible on their own. Without a comparative, listeners or readers will understand it based on context. This is known as a **null comparative** ([ODLT](http://www.odlt.org/ballast/null_comparative.html)).

The **than-clause** (or, more generally, a comparative clause [[ThoughtCo]](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-comparative-clause-1689880)) is optional. It can be used to clarify or emphasize what is being compared:

> John grew **smarter than he was before**.
>
> John grew **smarter than Jody**.
>
> Felicia became **more adept than she ever was before** at her work.
>
> As business grows **more complex than it had been**, I have trouble handling it.

Comment: Hi @TaliesinMerlin,, some where I found sentence like `more than enough money`, is this perfect to write or need some corrections ?

Comment: I have finished my mashed potatoes, can I have more mashed potatoes? Please?

Comment: @RajeshS - "more than enough money" is correct and normal. For instance, "I have more than enough money to buy the sandwich." means that I can buy the sandwich and still have money left afterward.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use *more* in sentences without a comparison, as long as a "comparator" can be recovered by context or inference. So, also yes, what is being compared is implied.

This is true for all comparative adjectives, not just those that require *more* to make the comparative form. These example adjectives each follow a different rule for comparative formation:  *tall* --> *taller*, *happy* --> *happier*, *good* --> *better*, *complex* --> *more complex*.

Here are some examples with [elliptical] (omitted) comparisons:

> *Math is hard. But English is harder [than Math].*
>
> *I used to be very sad. Now I am happier [than I used to be].*
>
> *What doesn't kill you makes you stronger [than you were before you survived death].*
>
> *Did you try their new restaurant? It's much better [than their old restaurant].*
>
> *In the past business was simple. As business grows more complex [than it was in the past], I'm unable to handle it.*

I think you can see that it's usually stylistically better to let context do the work [than to explicitly restate what can be inferred].

<sub>Further reading: [Comparative Adjectives](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/adjectives-comparative.htm)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

clausal comparisons:

As business grows more complex [than did in past], I'm unable to handle it.

correction: As business grows more complex **than it was in the pas**t, I'm unable to handle it.

**As questions become more repetitive than they were in the past**, my patience wears thing.

the comparison "than it was in the past" applies to the entire clause.

- The sun felt hotter today than it did yesterday.
- The child seems happier than he was last week.

Answer (score 0):

OED

> More (adv.) 
>   c. Modifying an adjective or adverb to form the comparative.

More (adv.) = To a greater extent; increasingly. **Increasingly** implies an increase of those circumstance (or quantity) that were the case.

As business grows more …..complex,

…………………adverb….adjective

…………………[adverbial phrase]

………………...[….complement…]

More complex is the comparative of complex ("complexer" is non-standard.)

Comment: but if "complexer" is non standard then also "business" should be compared with something else, right?

Comment: As in, a comparative degree should be used when you're comparing 2 things.

Comment: It means what you said in your question - more complex than it was in the past.

Comment: Tell me more!!  I want more!!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a dictionary, you will see there are multiple definitions for "more".

Without the conjunction "than", which introduces the second element in a comparison, "more" can simply mean "additional".

For example:

> Can I have more coffee?

This is understood to mean you have had some coffee, and are now having additional coffee. There is no comparison between the previous amount and the second helping.